# Show that two sides of a triangle are perpendicular

Tags: calculus, coordinate-systems, plane-geometry

$A(1.2, 3.8)$ , $B(2, 1.8)$ , $C(5, 3)$ are points on a coordinate grid.

I need to know how to show that the line segments $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{BC}$ are perpendicular. Not sure where to start on this one so just any help that would give a hint or help me get started would be appreciated.

All I know is that if the product of two gradients is -1 then the lines are perpendicular. Thanks.

Comment: This is a [PSQ](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), which is generally not considered to be a [good question](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ). Consider checking out [How to ask homework questions?](https://goo.gl/Fyfb22) for more details on how you can improve this.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt edited the question. Tell me if I can do anything else

Comment: First bullet of [How to ask a good question? : Context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/272831) is *"Include your work"*. Not necessary, but very useful.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I'll try

Comment: Kinda weird looking back on all these questions huh?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt these are from my GCSE. I'm not doing maths any further I don't think but I'm looking at studying physics so some of it may come in useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is $3$ nice answer on this question. But there is an elementary solution which you probably will like it. Use Pythagorean theorem!

$$|AB|^2=4+0.64$$
$$|BC|^2=9+1.44$$
$$|AC|^2=14.44+0.64$$

So $AB \perp BC$. That's it.

Comment: that's actually so smart, much better than proving the negative reciprocal identity! +1

Comment: @SakethMalyala Thanks for your kind comment. I appreciate that.

Answer (score 2):

Slope of segment $\overline{AB}$ = $\dfrac{1.8-3.8}{2-1.2} = \dfrac{-2}{0.8} = \dfrac{-5}{2}$.
Slope of segment $\overline{BC}$ = $\dfrac{3-1.8}{5-2} = \dfrac{1.2}{3} = \dfrac{2}{5}$

The slope of segment $\overline{AB}$ is the negative reciprocal of the slope of segment $\overline{BC}$ and thus is perpendicular.

Comment: Hi, I'm from the UK so the language differs slightly. Are slope and gradient the same thing?

Comment: @Charlie Yes They are the same

Comment: What do you mean when you say the negative reciprocal?

Comment: @Charlie Negative reciprocal of $x$ is  $\dfrac{-1}{x}$

Answer (score 1):

I am using vectors for this one.Since : $$\overrightarrow {a} \cdot \overrightarrow {b} = |\overrightarrow {a}||\overrightarrow {b}| \cos{\theta}$$Therefore, if two vectors are perpendicular $\implies \theta = 90^{\circ} \implies \cos \theta =0 \implies \overrightarrow {a} \cdot \overrightarrow {b} = 0 $
$\overrightarrow {AB} = -0.8 \hat i + 2\hat j$

$\overrightarrow {BC} = -3 \hat i + -1.2\hat j$

$\overrightarrow {AB} \cdot \overrightarrow {BC}= (0.8) \cdot (-3) +(2)(-1.2) = 0 \implies \overrightarrow {AB} \bot \overrightarrow {BC}$

Comment: You can explain why you used dot product of vectors for better understanding of the OP...

Comment: @tatan good idea.

Comment: What do the i and j represent?

Comment: @Charlie Have you studied vectors? They represent unit vectors along $x$ and $y$ axis.

Comment: @Charlie They are the unit vectors in the $x$ and $y$ directions...

Answer (score 0):

The line segment $AB$ passes through points $A$ and $B$. So,the line $AB$ with equation (let) $y=m_1x+c_1$ satisfies $A(1.2,3.8)$ and $B(2,1.8)$.So $AB$ is satisfied by $$3.8=1.2m_1+c_1$$ and $$1.8=2m_1+c_1$$.Solving we get the equation of $AB$ with slope $m_1=-2.5$.

Similarly solving for slope $m_2$ for line $BC$ we get $m_2=0.4$.

So,$m_2\times m_1=-1$.Hence the lines are perpendicular.

**If you didn't know this before you may note it as a theorem that if the product of slopes of two lines are $=-1$ then the lines are perpendicular to each other.**